# pair ios device to mac via bluetooth, and send keyboard command

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

is there any way to create an ios app that can pair ios device(iphone/ipad) to Mac/PC, so I can send a command like wireless keyboard sent to Mac/PC?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot connect an iPhone to another device for file transfer; the only profiles supported are hands-free and tethering. (Read the rest of the thread for details). There are many ways to transfer data between an iPhone and other devices, but BlueTooth is not on the list.

Also [this link](http://techchannel.radioshack.com/can-iphone-imac-via-bluetooth-2223.html) may help you.

Comment: it says there some app that can make your iphone as a Bluetooth wireless mouse. how can I do that? any clue?

Answer (score -4):

nevermind,

I've found the way to communicate

Comment: Would you mind posting some information about how you are doing it?